# Transferring & Deleting Files From SFTP Using SFTP Foreign Module

Tags: perl, unix, sftp, delete-file

My requirement is to transfer files and folders from SFTP remote location to unix location. I am new to perl and shell scripting, and this has been very confusing. I tried using rget command from sftp foreign as shown below. But it doesn't work and it isn't getting transferred. How do I delete the files and folders after copying them from the sftp server?

```
use Net::SFTP::Foreign;

my $host       = "sftp.elsevier.com";
my $remote_dir = "sample/host";
my $localdir = "sample/local";
my $username   = "username";
my $password   = "password";
my $debug      = 0;

$sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new($host, timeout => 240,user => $username, password => $password) or $newerr = 1;
push @ERRORS, "Can't sftp to $host: $!\n" if $newerr;
myerr() if $newerr;
print "Connected to $host\n";

$sftp->rget($remote_dir, $localdir) or $newerr = 1;
push @ERRORS, "Cant tranfer\n" if $newerr;
myerr() if $newerr;
$sftp->disconnect if $newerr;
print "Files are transferred successfully\n";

#Deleting files

$sftp->setcwd($remote_dir) or $newerr = 1;
push @ERRORS, "Can't cd $!\n" if $newerr;
myerr()    if $newerr;
$sftp->disconnect if $newerr;

my $files = $sftp->ls or $newerr = 1;
push @ERRORS, "Can't get file list $!\n" if $newerr;
myerr() if $newerr;

foreach (@$files){
$sftp->remove($_) or $newerr = 1;
push @ERRORS, "Cant delete\n" if $newerr;
myerr() if $newerr;

print "Deleted files successfully\n";

#}
$sftp->disconnect;

sub myerr {
    print "Error: \n";
    print @ERRORS;
    exit 0;
}
```

Inside the SFTP location - sample/host, I have many folders and files which all need to be copied to the local unix server - sample/local and deleted from the remote location.

Comment: This is a bit off topic, but where did you learn this style of passing arguments to subs and doing error handling? Did you take this from some tutorial or other resource? I'd be *very* interested in a link, because this is unbelievable bad style.

Answer (score 7):

You need to get a good Perl book which will help you learn how to code Perl in a more *modern* style. I recommend [Learning Perl](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449303587). This should teach you some techniques in coding.

For example, always use `use strict;` and `use warnings;`. These two modules will catch about 99% of all coding errors.

Also, the standard way of doing an error check is to use the `or die` style syntax. This is a much more natural method than setting a variable, and then checking the variable, and if there is an error, then going to a subroutine:

```
$stfp->ls or die qq(Cannot access remote machine ) . HOST;
```

It would also be nice if you indented too. Makes following your code easier.

Perl has a standard that variables should be all lowercase, and the newest standard is to use underscores to help separate out variable names. Constants should be all uppercase.

You should also look at the module's complete documentation. For example, there's an `autodie` option when you create a `Net::SFTP::Foreign` object that will kill your `sftp` session on any failure. This simplifies coding because you don't have to check for errors.

You also need to know that `Net::SFTP::Foreign->ls` returns a *reference* to an array. Thus, you need to dereference that array. You also have to know that each entry in this *array reference* is actually a reference to a hash, and that the file name is under the `filename` key of that hash reference.

And one more tiny fact the document mentions: This program uses the Unix/Linux installed `ssh` client. If you don't have that `ssh` client installed, this just won't work.

You may want to look at the Perl Tutorial on [References](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html)

I've rewritten your program to take advantage of `autodie` and to use a bit more modern syntax. Normally, I would test this, but unfortunately, I don't have Net::SFTP::Foreign installed, and I don't have a remote computer I can use for testing:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);
use autodie;

use Net::SFTP::Foreign;

use constant {
    HOST            => "sftp.elsvier.com",
    REMOTE_DIR      => "sample/host",
    LOCAL_DIR       => "sample/local",
    USER_NAME       => "username",
    PASSWORD        => "password",
    DEBUG           => "0",
};

my $sftp;
$sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new (
    HOST,
    timeout         => 240,
    user            => USER_NAME,
    password        => PASSWORD,
    autodie         => 1,
);

#
# Fetch Files
#
$sftp->rget( REMOTE_DIR, LOCAL_DIR );

#
# Delete Files
#

$sftp->setcwd( REMOTE_DIR );
my @files = @{ $sftp->ls };  #Returns a reference to an array of hashes

for my $file ( @files ) {
    $sftp->remove( $file->{filename} ); #Reference to a hash
}

say "Deleted files successfully";

$sftp->disconnect;
```

Comment: I would like to add that `$sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new(...)` never fails. It always returns a valid object and you have to check `sftp->error` afterwards to see if the connection failed or as you have pointed just use the `autodie` feature.

Comment: @salva - I was going to write the example using `$sftp->error` after the `new` and each method call until I saw the `autodie` setting. I like `autodie`. All methods should be written to `autodie` on any failed method or constructor. Then, if the developer wants to continue, they have to use `eval` or `Try::Tiny` (which should be a standard module) to handle _the exception_. This way, you don't forget to handle an issue.

Comment: @salva I see the issue in my post now... When I gave an example of the `or die` syntax, I used the `new` constructor. I changed my example to use `$sftp->ls`. I examined the code, and you're correct: The `new` always returns a `Net::SFTP::Foreign` object. I also see that the developer is using `$sftp->{_option} = delete $opt{_option}`. This means if I set `option => 0` or `option => ``, the option will still be turned on. This also is against the way most modules are programed. Sometimes you really have to look at the code.

Comment: W: using `option => 0` or `option => ""` does disable the option.

Comment: @salva I looked at the code, and saw that they handled the setting of the settings section of the method by taking the status of a delete on the key. For example: `$sftp->{_autodie} = delete $opts{autodie};`. In my reading if I had set `autodie => 0`. then the `delete ${opts{autodie}` would still return _true_ because the key `autodie` still exists in the `$opts` hash even though the value for that element in the hash is `0`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @salva You're right. I misread the Perldoc on `delete`. It says "_in list context, returns the value or values deleted, or **the last such element in scalar context**._" I got confused with the Perldoc's discussion of how `exists` will return _false_.